# Hölder estimates of derivatives of harmonic function?

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations

In Gilbarg and Trudinger's textbook about elliptic equation, they give the following interior estimate of derivatives of harmonic function $v$ in $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ using the mean value theorem: for any $\Omega'\Subset \Omega$, denote $d=dist(\Omega',\partial \Omega )$, then we have
$$\sup_{\Omega'} |\partial^k u |\le \frac{C}{d^k}\sup_{\Omega}|u|$$
where $C$ depends on $n,k$. Moreover, I want to establish a interior Hölder estimate for $u$: for $B_1=B_R(x), B_2=B_{2R}(x)\subset \Omega$,
$$|u|_{2,\alpha;B_1}'\le C|u|_{0;B_2}, \text{ i.e. } R|\partial u |_{0;B_1}+R^2|\partial^2 u |_{0;B_1}+R^{2+\alpha}[\partial^2 u ]_{0;B_1}\le C|u|_{0;B_2} .$$
The first two terms can be controlled using the inequality by G-T directly, but how about the last term involving Hölder seminorm? I attempt to apply the mean value property again:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\frac{\partial^2 u (x)-\partial^2 u(y) }{|x-y|^\alpha} =\frac{1}{\omega_nR^n} \frac{ \int_{\partial B_R(x)} -\int_{\partial B_R(y) }\partial u(s)ds }{|x-y|^\alpha}.
\end{split}
\end{equation}
However, the right hand sees hard to estimate as it involves the difference between integral area. Can anyone give a more efficient method to estimate the Hölder term?

Comment: Can you use theorem 4.6 in the textbook(G-T)? It is standard Shauder estimate and it can be proved using estimates on potential for laplacian.

Comment: @Bergsom The goal of my estimate is exactly to prove theorem 4.6 (as in Theorem 4.6 the proof is not clear about part of the Hölder estimate of harmonic function).

Comment: For harmonic functions you can use bound on $C^3$ norm to estimate $C^{2,\alpha}$ norm. It is just better norm and we can do that since we know such bound for any $C^k,$ for harmonic functions.(as you mentioned at the begining of the post)